# Access violation on a private array inside a class

Tags: c++

```
For the most part this is borrowed code from RasterTeks DX11 tutorial that I am modified lightly or my own use and taste.  I am getting a read access violation while using the below InputClass to set keystates.

#include "InputClass.h"

InputClass::InputClass() { }
InputClass::InputClass(const InputClass& other) { }
InputClass::~InputClass() { }

void InputClass::Initialize() {
    // Initialize all the keys to being released and not pressed.
    for (int i = 0; i<256; i++) {
        keystate[i] = false;
    }

    return;
}


void InputClass::KeyDown(unsigned int input) {
    // If a key is pressed then save that state in the key array.
    keystate[input] = true;
    return;
}


void InputClass::KeyUp(unsigned int input) {
    // If a key is released then clear that state in the key array.
    keystate[input] = false;
    return;
}


bool InputClass::IsKeyDown(unsigned int input) {
    // Return what state the key is in (pressed/not pressed).
    return keystate[input];
}
```

Below is my main callback loop, the one registered with the WindowClass:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        // this message is read when the window is closed
    case WM_DESTROY: {
                         PostQuitMessage(0);
                         return 0;
    }
        // Check if the window is being closed.
    case WM_CLOSE: {
                       PostQuitMessage(0);
                       return 0;
    }
    default: { return ApplicationHandle->MessageHandler(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); }
    }
}
```

Finally, below is the secondary message handler that is a part of my SystemClass:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SystemClass::MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_KEYDOWN: { input->KeyDown((unsigned int)wparam); }
    case WM_KEYUP: { input->KeyUp((unsigned int)wparam); }
    default: { return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam); }
    }
}
```

The exception is fired off when the code gets to my switch/case/default list in the secondary message handler.  If I comment these lines out the program happily runs but of course, no input.

Any help or clues would be invaluable.  Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Where does the access violation occur? What is the full message?

Comment: What is a full error message? Insert missing parts: `Access violation <reading/writing/executing> location <address>`. After breakpoint hits your  code, watch variables and soon you will find the problem. If not, walk the call stack and watch variables at each step. I guess, it is uninitialized pointer.

Comment: We need your header file.

Comment: Where is `input` defined for `SystemClass::MessageHandler`?  Is it possibly null?

Answer (score 0):

Try following modification of your code:

```
void InputClass::KeyDown(unsigned int input) {
    if (input < 0 || input > 255)
        return;
    // If a key is pressed then save that state in the key array.
    keystate[input] = true;
    return;
}

void InputClass::KeyUp(unsigned int input) {
    if (input < 0 || input > 255)
        return;
    // If a key is released then clear that state in the key array.
    keystate[input] = false;
    return;
}
```

(since you haven't any problems in constructor of `InputClass`, it is not a problem of private status of array)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with no luck.  I will leave the code in just in case of error, but it called an access violation in the same place.

I will include missing information below.

```
//inputclass.h

class InputClass
{
public:
    InputClass();
    InputClass(const InputClass&);
    ~InputClass();

    void Initialize();

    void KeyDown(unsigned int);
    void KeyUp(unsigned int);
    bool IsKeyDown(unsigned int);

//private:
    bool keystate[256];
};

//systemclass.h

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include "InputClass.h"

class SystemClass {
public:
    SystemClass();
    ~SystemClass();

    void Startup();
    bool InitializeWindows(HWND);
    void ShutDown();
    void Run();

    LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

    int GetWindowPosX();
    int GetWindowPosY();
    int GetWindowWidth();
    int GetWindowHeight();

private:
    HWND hWnd;
    InputClass* input;
    int posX, posY, windowWidth, windowHeight;
};

static SystemClass* ApplicationHandle = 0;

//main.cpp

#include "systemclass.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPreviousInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    SystemClass* system;
    system = new SystemClass;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Engine";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    system->Startup();
    if(!(system->InitializeWindows(CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                                            L"Engine",
                                            L"Engine",
                                            WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
                                            system->GetWindowPosX(),
                                            system->GetWindowPosY(),
                                            system->GetWindowWidth(),
                                            system->GetWindowHeight(),
                                            NULL,
                                            NULL,
                                            hInstance,
                                            NULL)))) return 0;
    system->Run();
    system->ShutDown();
    UnregisterClass(L"Engine", hInstance);
    delete system;
    system = 0;

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        // this message is read when the window is closed
    case WM_DESTROY: {
                         PostQuitMessage(0);
                         return 0;
    }
        // Check if the window is being closed.
    case WM_CLOSE: {
                       PostQuitMessage(0);
                       return 0;
    }
    default: { return ApplicationHandle->MessageHandler(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); }
    }
}

//systemclass.cpp

#include "SystemClass.h"

SystemClass::SystemClass() { }
SystemClass::~SystemClass() { }

void SystemClass::Startup() {
    ApplicationHandle = this;
    windowWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    windowHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    input = new InputClass;
    input->Initialize();
    int fc = MessageBox(NULL, L"Engine", L"Fullscreen?", MB_YESNO);
    switch (fc) {
    case 7: {
                posX = (windowWidth - 800) / 2;
                posY = (windowHeight - 600) / 2;
                windowWidth = 800;
                windowHeight = 600;
    }
    case 6: {
                DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;
                posX = posY = 0;
                ZeroMemory(&dmScreenSettings, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));
                dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
                dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = (unsigned long)windowWidth;
                dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = (unsigned long)windowHeight;
                dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = 32;
                dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

                // Change the display settings to full screen.
                ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    }
}

bool SystemClass::InitializeWindows(HWND ihWnd) { 
    hWnd = ihWnd;
    if (hWnd) {
        //system->InitializeWindows(hWnd);
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        SetFocus(hWnd);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        MessageBoxEx(NULL, L"Could not create window.", L"ERROR!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION, NULL);
        return false;
    }


}

void SystemClass::ShutDown() {
    delete input;
    input = 0;
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    hWnd = NULL;
    ApplicationHandle = NULL;
}

void SystemClass::Run() {
    bool done;
    MSG msg;
    done = false;
    while (!done) {
        // Handle the windows messages.
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (input->IsKeyDown(VK_ESCAPE)) { 
            done = true;
            MessageBoxEx(NULL, L"input broken.", L"ERROR!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION, NULL);

        }
        // If windows signals to end the application then exit out.
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) { done = true; }
    }

}

int SystemClass::GetWindowPosX(){ return posX; }

int SystemClass::GetWindowPosY() { return posY; }

int SystemClass::GetWindowWidth() { return windowWidth; }

int SystemClass::GetWindowHeight() { return windowHeight; }

LRESULT CALLBACK SystemClass::MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_KEYDOWN: { input->KeyDown((unsigned int)wparam); }
    case WM_KEYUP: { input->KeyUp((unsigned int)wparam); }
    default: { return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam); }
    }
}
```

The error message given when when I hit the escape key:
Unhandled exception at 0x00881E08 in DX11 Engine 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

OK: this is where it gets interesting, the values in the local field (specific to the second callback function) are as follows:
lparam: 65537
wparam: 27
message: 256
hwnd: 0x01b80460 {unused=???}
this: 0x00000000

The value of hwnd, wparam, and lparam are all displayed in red.

I feel like the values are supposed to tell me something about what is going on here but I just don't really understand.  Is there a reason why the variable "this" is set to adress 0x00000000?  this is a pointer to an instance of the systemclass... or it's supposed to be.

Also, the unused comment in hwnd throws me off, though I'm not sure what is going wrong there since the program is very clearly at least DETECTING a keypress attributed to the window.

I hope this helps anyone with any ideas.

EDIT: You got me looking for a misused pointer and I discovered it had EVERYTHING to do with the "this" pointer and the way I was using system and ApplicationHandle.  I fixed it by changing ApplicationHandle to system and simply using the same pointer everywhere.  The way I was using it before was illogical and senseless.

Thank you all for helping me find it!